# function already has a body error code C2084

Tags: compiler-errors, composition

I am trying to use Stock object as member of the BuyOrder class. When I implement the constructor for BuyOrder, it shows that function 'BuyOder::BuyOrder(double,int,Stock)' already has a body. Any help?

```
 BuyOrder::BuyOrder(double price, int quantity, Stock s)
 :buyPrice{ price },
  buyQuantity{quantity},
  buyStock{s}{}
```

And in the header file, the constructor prototype is

```
BuyOrder(double price, int quantity, Stock s) {}
```

Comment: In the header change `{}` to `;` . And add a language tag

Comment: Thanks you! Solved!